# android databinding switch listener doesn't work

Tags: android, xml, android-databinding

So I created `val isSwitchChecked = ObservableBoolean(false)` variable and added to XML on switch like this `android:checked="@={viewmodel.isSwitchChecked()}"` because I want to set it checked with boolean when I'm loading data and everything works fine till I'm adding `OnCheckedChangeListener` then switch doesn't react on listener unless I'm removing this `android:checked="@={viewmodel.isSwitchChecked()}"` from xml. What's going on? and how can I make it that it would work both ways?

Comment: correct me if im wrong, you mean that you already have set the binding but you still need to set the on checked change listener?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you are doing is wrong.

#### Reason of fail

If you are setting two way binding on Switch, then `OnCheckedChangeListener` programmatically will not work. Because internally two way binding is dependent on `OnCheckedChangeListener`.

#### Correct way

If you are doing two way binding, then set check change listener also by binding. I tell you some ways.

**Here are ways to set `OnCheckedChangeListener` in data binding :**

### (1) Set by [method expression](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions)

**In layout**

```
<variable
    name="activity"
    type="com.innovanathinklabs.sample.activities.CalendarActivity"/>

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="@={model.checked}"
    android:onCheckedChanged="@{activity::onGenderChanged}"
    />
```

**In Activity**

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityCalendarBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_calendar)
        binding.activity = this
        binding.model = Model()
    }

    fun onGenderChanged(buttonView: CompoundButton, isChecked: Boolean) {
        println("buttonView = [$buttonView], isChecked = [$isChecked]")
    }
}
```

### (2) Set by [lambda expression](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions) and method call

```
<variable
    name="model"
    type="com.innovanathinklabs.sample.data.Model"/>

<variable
    name="activity"
    type="com.innovanathinklabs.sample.activities.HomeActivity"/>

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="@={model.checked}"
    android:onCheckedChanged="@{(button, bool)-> activity.saveGender(bool)}"
    />
```

In Activity

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityCalendarBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_calendar)
        binding.activity = this
        binding.model = Model()
    }

    fun saveGender(isChecked: Boolean) {
        println("isChecked = [$isChecked]")
    }
}
```

### (3) Pass `OnCheckedChangeListener` anonymous class to layout

```
<variable
    name="onGenderChange"
    type="android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener"/>

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="@={model.checked}"
    android:onCheckedChanged="@{onGenderChange}"
    />
```

In Activity

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityCalendarBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_calendar)
        binding.model = Model()
        binding.setOnGenderChange { buttonView, isChecked ->
            println("buttonView = [$buttonView], isChecked = [$isChecked]")
        }
    }
}
```

### (4) Pass `OnCheckedChangeListener` by reference

```
<variable
    name="onGenderChange2"
    type="android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener"/>

<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="@={model.checked}"
    android:onCheckedChanged="@{onGenderChange2}"
    />
```

Activity

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityCalendarBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_calendar)
        binding.model = Model()
        binding.onGenderChange2 = onGenderChange
    }

    private val onGenderChange: CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener = CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        println("buttonView = [$buttonView], isChecked = [$isChecked]")
    }
}
```

### This will never work

Because you can't set two callback on one component. One callback is already set by two way binding, so your callback will not work.

```
binding.mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
    println("buttonView = [$buttonView], isChecked = [$isChecked]")
}
```

[Check **CompoundButtonBindingAdapter** class](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/3b920788e90bb0abe615a5d5c899915f0014444b/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/android/databinding/adapters/CompoundButtonBindingAdapter.java) to see how Switch Binding works.

Comment: Let me know if you want this solution in Java?